# Using local storage to save image in javascript

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Check my JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oxfre6kj/1/

I have a button that creates as many images as you want, but when I refresh the page those images are gone, I want them to be still there after I click the save button.

Here is what I tried it works with variable but it doesn't work with "img"

```
<button onclick="createImage()">Create Image</button>
<button onclick="saveImages()">Save Images</button>
<div id="image"></div>

<script>
function createImage() {
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150';       
        document.getElementById('image').appendChild(img);
}


var image = localStorage.getItem('image');
alert(image);

function saveImage() {
    localStorage.setItem("images", image);
}
</script>
```

Comment: You cannot (and should not) store an entire DOM element in local storage. Just store the number of images you have appended (or an array of urls if they're different images).

Comment: Can you show me how?

Comment: you call `saveImages` but your function is called `saveImage`, without `s`.

Comment: Locastorage can only save strings,  so you can only store an image by serializing it (e.g. base64 encoding it). Note that localStorage has a limited capacity, which will almost certainly be exceeded.

Answer (score 1):

is this how you want the page to work ?

HTML :

```html
<button id="create_image">Create Image</button>
<button onclick="saveImages()">Save Images</button>

<label for="image_url">Image url :</label>
<input type="text" id="image_url" value="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded" placeholder="img url">

<div id="images"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT :

```js
document.getElementById("create_image").addEventListener("click", function() {
  const url = document.getElementById("image_url").value;
  createImage(url);
});

var images = localStorage.getItem('image');
loadImagesFromLocal();

function createImage(src) {
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = src;
  img.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('images').appendChild(img);
  }
}

function saveImages(img) {
  const images = document.querySelectorAll(`div#images img`);
  var savedImagesSrc = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("images")) || [];
  savedImagesSrc = Array.from(savedImagesSrc);

  for (var i = savedImagesSrc.length; i < images.length; i++) {
    savedImagesSrc.push(images[i].src);
  }

  localStorage.setItem("images", JSON.stringify(savedImagesSrc));
}

function loadImagesFromLocal() {
  const savedImagesSrc = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("images")) || [];

  for (var i = 0; i < savedImagesSrc.length; i++) {
    createImage(savedImagesSrc[i]);
  }

}
```